# Textbox3 update to active cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code for textbox3:

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
NextFree = Range("d6:d" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
Range("d" & NextFree).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
```

The output is something like this:
I cell d7
Ia cell d8
Iam cell d9
Iama cell d10
 where the same should be in cell d7, it should the output as "Iama". Any Idea as were I am going wrong?

Comment: You are looking for the next empty cell, every time the value of your textbox changes. that means if you are writing the value with every change, the next empty cell will shift one to the left. Also dont use `.Select`just use `Range("D" & NextFree).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value`

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: Ofc. Depends on what you want to do.

Comment: got it.    Private Sub TextBox3_Change()NextFree = Range("d6:d" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = Me.TextBox3.Value
End Sub

Comment: thanks working fine now